# In one page Using Multiple tab controls each tab control have one Component

Tags: angular

In one page using Multiple tab controls, each tab control has one component.
When click on tab, it opens only that type of component. When click another  tab it opens related component only

- Tab 1  tab1-Component
- Tab 2  tab2-Component
- Tab 3  tab3-Component
- Tab 4  tab4-Component

All tabs are showing in single page only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a container component which actually holds the other components but the components will be opening as to clicking on the respective tabs. So I think you could organize the templates as the following:

**tab-container-component.html:**

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
        <app-tab1-component></app-tab1-component>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
        <app-tab2-component></app-tab2-component>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 3">
        <app-tab3-component></app-tab3-component>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 4">
        <app-tab4-component></app-tab4-component>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**tab1-component.html:**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    Tab1 Component works!
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**tab2-component.html:**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    Tab2 Component works!
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**tab3-component.html:**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    Tab3 Component works!
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**tab4-component.html:**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    Tab4 Component works!
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```